# .htaccess Rewrite rules not firing

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, rule

I am trying to come up with a rewrite rule that will rewrite:

oldurl.com/v11/file.ext to newurl.com/v11/file.ext

On the oldurl server I have put the following in .htaccess inside of the folder v11:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^v11/(.*)$ http://newurl.com/v11/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But the redirect is not firing at all.  What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

When placing .htaccess in the v11 folder, your code should be:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newurl.com/v11/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `/v11` folder is inside the regex group and back reference $1 will add it again to the substitution URL, like this: `http://newurl.com/v11/v11/file.ext`.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the new server is set up to allow .htaccess files to be read at the directory level.

If the .htaccess file worked on the other server, it is most likely a server configuration issue or file owner/permissions problem.